# How to select all objects for specified type, for example, IfcWallStandardCase?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

how to select all objects which belongs to specific type, for example all doors or all windows?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to use `viewer.search` (docs [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/viewer3d/#search-text-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback-attributenames)) and then select the dbids returned. Note that the search is async and the results are supplied as a number array:

```
viewer.search('keyword', function(dbids){
   if(dbids instanceof Array && dbids.length)
     viewer.select(dbids)
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much.